# decoded and encoded text are not equal to each other

Tags: modular-arithmetic

i know that it is  related to the  programming a bit more, but  i think mathematical issue as well, for instance there is given my code

```
 function result=affine_cipher_encode(a,b,m,s)
    %a and b  are prime numbers
    % m=total number of  letters in english language(26)
    %s-input string 
    % result=output after  affine  chiper algorithm
    n=length(s);% declare length of  string
    letter=['a':'z'];% declare array of letters with following index 'a'=1,b='2',..'z'=26;
    result=zeros(size(s));
    for ii=1:n
       if ~isspace(s(ii))
           index=find(letter==s(ii));
           c=mod((a*index+b),m);
           converted_letter=letter(c);
           result(ii)=converted_letter;

       else
           continue;
       end


    end
    result=char(result);
    end
```

which uses Affine  cipher  function
$c=a*p+b\pmod m$
this line works successfully, there is my example

```
a=5;
b=7;
m=26;
s='wbgbuwyqbbhtynhkkzgyqbrhtykb';
result=affine_cipher_encode(a,b,m,s)

result =

rqpqhrbnqqucbyujjgpbnqsucbjq
```

after that, i decided  to write code for decoding given result , for that i use multiplicative inverse of   $a$ modulo $m$, so i wrote following code

```
function decode=affine_cipher_decode(a,b,m,result)
%a and b  are prime numbers
% m=total number of  letters in english language(26)
%s-input string 
% decodet=output after  affine  chiper decoding algorithm
n=length(result);% declare length of  string
letter=['a':'z'];% declare array of letters with following index 'a'=1,b='2',..'z'=26;
decode=zeros(size(result));
 %find  multiplicative inverse of  a and m 
[g,x,d] = gcd(a,m); 
x = mod(x,m);  % find multiplicative inverse 
for ii=1:n
     if ~isspace(result(ii))
          index=find(letter==result(ii));
          p=mod(x*(index-b),m);
          if p==0
              c=mod(a*index+b,m);
              decode(ii)=letter(c);
          else
          converted_letter=letter(p);
       decode(ii)=converted_letter;
          end
     else
         continue;
     end
end
decode=char(decode);
```

but there was problem, my $p$  value which can be  calculated  by

$p=x*(c-b)\pmod m$

but  at one fragment of code, i am getting $p=0$  which causes error, that  why for  recovering of original index, i  added  following fragment

```
 if p==0
                  c=mod(a*index+b,m);
                  decode(ii)=letter(c);
```

but  i am getting one place different,  between original  and decoding  text,so  where i am getting mistake? please help me

Comment: Is this in matlab?

Comment: yes  it is, currently i am working in matlab

Comment: If it is modulo 26, shouldn't your indexes go from 0 to 25 ? Because as it is, you have z=0, a=1, b=2, ...., y=25, so indeed for p=0 you should assign z instead of raising an error. Better to work with arrays from 0..n-1 than 1..n.

Comment: thanks for your replay but in matlab there  is not  array with  zero index

Comment: now it works thanks for reply

Comment: but any way  it has some bugs